FMOD: OpenStateReady Changes to OpenStateSetPosition Without setPosition Call - How to Fix?
I used the CREATE_STREAM and NONBLOCKING flags to create a stream in FMOD, and I confirmed that the state was OpenStateReady. However, in the next frame, without calling setPosition or getPosition, the state changed to OpenStateSetPosition.
As a result, I’m unable to change the stream position using setPosition. How can I resolve this issue?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
